# Rotate a 2D NxN matrix in Concentric Circles

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

Given a 2D NxN matrix, visualize it as concentric circles. You have to find the rotated matrix where each element in the circle is rotated by 1 position layer by layer in an alternate clockwise and anticlockwise direction. All rotations should be in-place.

```
2 3 4 5
1 6 7 8
4 2 1 9
5 3 2 4
```

should get transformed to

```
1 2 3 4 
4 7 1 5 
5 6 2 8 
3 2 4 9
```

I thought about the solution

1> For clockwise circle rotation, read elements in the order

```
i -> 0 to n-1 and j = 0
j -> 0 to n-1 and i = n-1
i -> n-1 to 0 and j = n-1
j -> n-1 to 0 and i = 0
```

2> For anti-clockwise circle rotation, read elements in the order

```
j -> 0 to n-1 and i = 0
i -> 0 to n-1 and j = n-1
j -> n-1 to 0 and i = n-1
i -> n-1 to 0 and j = 0
```

Code

```
for(int cnt = 0; cnt < n/2; cnt++)
    {   
        if(cnt%2 == 0) // Clockwise
        {   
            i = cnt; j = cnt;
            // while loops for each case
        }
        else // anti-clockwise
        {
            i = cnt; j = cnt;
            // while loops for each case
        }       
}
```

Is there any better approach to solve this problem in O(n2) or better ?

Comment: you have the full code ?

Answer (score 5):

As your array is of size N*N and the desired computation demands each element to be visited atleast once, there cannot be a solution better than `O(n^2)` which uses 2 dimensional arrays.

I think that your solution will be fine if the operation has to be done single time on the same array.

If you have to do this operation multiple times on the same input array, better create circles from the input array. The data structure of circle should be a CLL (circular linked list). So doing the operation multiple times will be piece of cake as you have to change the root element of the CLL storing the circle info depending on the direction.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this can be solved easily in-place in O(n) time.

(NOTE: O(N) where N is the total number of matrix elements)

The following solution doesn't use four consecutive loops, but uses a small table of `[X, Y]` deltas that describe the difference between the current coordinate and the next one, when the next coordinate is invalid (i.e outside of the current window) the index to the table itself is advanced and the look-up repeated. The algorithm starts with full window and decreases it by one element from each side every time the nested loop finishes. The whole process repeats until the window defined as `[minX, minY, maxX, maxY]` is valid (i.e. contains at least 2x2 elements).

This solution doesn't implement swapping cw and ccw, but this is the easiest part to add.

```js
function pad(s, n) {
  while(s.length < n)
    s = " " + s;
  return s;
}

// Create a matrix of [WxH] size.
function Matrix(w, h, data) {
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    if (data.length !== w * h)
      throw new Error("Data.length has to match the size " + (w * h) + ".");
  }
  else {
    var n = typeof data === "number" ? data : 0.0;
    data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < w*h; i++) data.push(n);
  }

  this.w = w;
  this.h = h;
  this.data = data;
}

// Get value at [x, y]
Matrix.prototype.get = function(x, y) {
  if (x < 0 || x >= this.w || y < 0 || y >= this.h)
    throw new Error("Index [" + x + ", " + y + "] out of bounds");
  return this.data[y * this.w + x];
}

// Set value at [x, y] and return the previous value.
Matrix.prototype.set = function(x, y, value) {
  if (x < 0 || x >= this.w || y < 0 || y >= this.h)
    throw new Error("Index [" + x + ", " + y + "] out of bounds");

  var i = y * this.w + x;
  var prev = this.data[i];

  this.data[i] = value;
  return prev;
}

// Log the matrix data.
Matrix.prototype.dump = function() {
  var s = "["
  var i = 0;
  for (var y = 0; y < this.h; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < this.w; x++, i++) {
      s += pad("" + this.data[i], 2);
      if (x !== this.w - 1)
        s += ","
    }
    if (y !== this.h - 1)
      s += ",\n ";
  }
  s += "]";
  console.log(s);
}

// Shift, `dir` can be "cw" or "ccw".
Matrix.prototype.shift = function(dir) {
  var instructions = {
    cw : [1, 0, 0, 1,-1, 0, 0,-1],
    ccw: [0, 1, 1, 0, 0,-1,-1, 0]
  };
 
  var inst = instructions[dir];

  // A window, shrink by one from each side after the nested loop is done.
  var minX = 0;
  var minY = 0;
  var maxX = this.w - 1;
  var maxY = this.h - 1;

  while (minX < maxX && minY < maxY) {
    // Always start at the top-left corner and iterate.
    var x0 = minX;
    var y0 = minY;
    var v0 = this.get(x0, y0);
    var n = 0;

    for (;;) {
      var x1 = x0 + inst[n + 0];
      var y1 = y0 + inst[n + 1];

      if (x1 < minX || x1 > maxX || y1 < minY || y1 > maxY) {
        n += 2;
        x1 = x0 + inst[n + 0];
        y1 = y0 + inst[n + 1];
      }

      v0 = this.set(x1, y1, v0);

      // Last one.
      if (x1 === minX && y1 === minY)
        break;

      x0 = x1;
      y0 = y1;
    }

    minX++;
    minY++;
    maxX--;
    maxY--;
  }
}

var a = new Matrix(3, 3, [
  1,2,3,
  4,5,6,
  7,8,9,
]);

a.dump();
a.shift("cw");
a.dump();

var b = new Matrix(4, 4, [
  1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,
  5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,
  9 ,10,11,12,
  13,14,15,16
]);

b.dump();
b.shift("ccw");
b.dump();
```

Comment: It's definitely O(n); it's visible from the code. If you are not sure you can try it out.

Comment: Trying it out, I have counted how many times your code reached the for(;;) statement, which will count how many times the largest group of operations are being repeated, and hence will determine the complexity. Here are the results:

n = 3 -> 8 times
n = 4 -> 16 times
n = 5 -> 24 times
n = 6 -> 36 times
[...]

So, it is n^2 when n is even and (n^2) -1 when n is odd, which gives us O(n^2). This makes sense since the only element not touched is right in the middle when n is odd. As said by Tejas Patil, there is no way of doing this is less than O(n^2). Anyway, nice answer, very clever algorithm.

Comment: I think that there is a bit of misunderstanding. For me the code is O(N), because AxB matrix has N elements total, so it's linear time because every element is touched exactly once (more specifically it's read and written once). Please note that matrix doesn't have to be square, the code will work regardless of matrix size. In other words, I counted the number of data elements and calculated the complexity based on that.

For example populating the matrix:

`for (var i = 0; i < w*h; i++) data.push(n);`

is also linear for me, etc :) I hope I made it clear, thanks for your point of view.

Comment: BTW just to finish my thoughts. The code I wrote will work well for small matrices, but will not perform well for large matrices when doing vertical shifts. The reason is that it will do basically random memory access. The code can be improved by always accessing matrix elements sequentially (this means shifting always in horizontal direction), but this would really complicate the solution and if this was my concern I wouldn't have used javascript for the answer. However, if you are doing an interview this is something that should be mentioned.

Comment: Very cool solution. It's `O(n)` because you've redefined the meaning of `n`. It's `O(n^2)` when using the `n` value that most people associate with the problem (the length of a one of the outer arrays). So what used to be O(n) = O(3^2) ~= 8 is now O(n) = O(9) ~= 8. So changing `n` didn't only affect the complexity notation input to but the formula and result as well. Note `~=` because the numbers quoted above by counting don't seem to be perfect squares but are close to them. Perhaps they were not counted right.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem recently in a job interview and I failed to solve it in under one hour.

Then I got home and produced the code below in java. It is recursive and I believe it has O(n^2) complexity. You can also see the code here: https://github.com/lotif/rotateMatrix

You will have first to input the dimension of the (square) matrix and then the numbers of the matrix itself separated by spaces, line by line. For instance:

3

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

It will return you the matrix rotated clockwise in concentric circles.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RotateMatrix {

    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int d = s.nextInt();

        int[][] matrix = new int[d][d];
        for(int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < d; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(s.next());
            }
        }

        matrix = rotate(matrix);

        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        s.close();
    }

    public static int[][] rotate(int[][] matrix) {
        if(matrix == null || matrix.length == 0 || matrix.length == 1) {
            return matrix;
        }

        List<Integer> outerCircle = getOuterCircle(matrix);
        matrix = removeOuterCircle(matrix);
        //rotating outer circle
        outerCircle.add(0, outerCircle.remove(outerCircle.size() - 1));

        matrix = rotate(matrix);

        matrix = addOuterCircle(outerCircle, matrix);

        return matrix;

    }

    private static int[][] addOuterCircle(List<Integer> outerCircle, int[][] matrix) {

        int d = matrix.length + 2;
        int[][] newMatrix = new int[d][d];

        //Adding the outer circle to the matrix
        for(int j = 0; j < d; j++) {
            newMatrix[0][j] = outerCircle.remove(0);
        }
        for(int i = 1; i < d; i++) {
            newMatrix[i][d-1] = outerCircle.remove(0);
        }
        for(int j = d-2; j >= 0; j--) {
            newMatrix[d-1][j] = outerCircle.remove(0);
        }
        for(int i = d-2; i >= 1; i--) {
            newMatrix[i][0] = outerCircle.remove(0);
        }

        //Adding the inner matrix
        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                newMatrix[i + 1][j + 1] = matrix[i][j];
            }
        }

        return newMatrix;

    }

    private static List<Integer> getOuterCircle(int[][] matrix) {
        int d = matrix.length;

        List<Integer> outerCircle = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int j = 0; j < d; j++) {
            outerCircle.add(matrix[0][j]);
        }
        for(int i = 1; i < d; i++) {
            outerCircle.add(matrix[i][d-1]);
        }
        for(int j = d-2; j >= 0; j--) {
            outerCircle.add(matrix[d-1][j]);
        }
        for(int i = d-2; i >= 1; i--) {
            outerCircle.add(matrix[i][0]);
        }

        return outerCircle;
    }

    private static int[][] removeOuterCircle(int[][] matrix) {      
        int d = matrix.length;
        int[][] newMatrix = new int[d-2][d-2];

        for(int i = 1; i < d-1; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j < d-1; j++) {
                newMatrix[i-1][j-1] = matrix[i][j];
            }
        }

        return newMatrix;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ShiftArray {
    static void shiftArray(int[][]a, int index, int n) {
       if ((n%2 == 0) && (index >= n/2))
           return;
       if ((n%2 != 0) && (index > n/2))
           return;

       int tempRowTopLast = a[index][n-1-index]; 
       int tempColRightLast = a[n-1-index][n-1-index];
       int tempRowBottomLast = a[n-1-index][index]; 
       int tempColLeftLast = a[index][index];

       int temp, temp2;

       temp = tempColLeftLast; 

       for (int k = index + 1; k < n-index; k++) {
           temp2 = a[index][k];
           a[index][k] = temp;
           temp = temp2;
       }

       temp = tempRowTopLast; 
       for (int k = index + 1; k < n-index; k++) {
           temp2 = a[k][n-1-index];
           a[k][n-1-index] = temp; 
           temp = temp2; 
       }

       temp = tempColRightLast; 
       for (int k = n-2-index; k >=index; k--) {
           temp2 = a[n-1-index][k];
           a[n-1-index][k] = temp; 
           temp = temp2; 
       }

       temp = tempRowBottomLast;
       for (int k = n-2-index; k >=index; k--) {
           temp2 = a[k][index];
           a[k][index] = temp;
           temp = temp2;
       } 

       shiftArray(a, index+1, n);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[][] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

        shiftArray(a, 0, 3);
        System.out.println("Rotated array...");

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + ",");
            }
            System.out.println();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Additional explanation would improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RotateMatrix
{
    static int rows = 0;
    static int cols = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        rows = scan.nextInt();
        cols = scan.nextInt();
        int rots = scan.nextInt();
        int[][] matrix = new int[rows][cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rots; i++)
            rotate(matrix, 0, rows - 1, 0, cols - 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        scan.close();
    }

    public static int[][] rotate(int[][] arr, int rowStart, int rowEnd, int colStart, int colEnd)
    {

        if (rowStart == rowEnd && colStart == colEnd)
        {
            return arr;
        }
        if (rowStart > rowEnd || colStart > colEnd)
        {
            return arr;
        }

        int temp = arr[rowStart][colStart];
        for (int j = colStart; j < colEnd; j++)
        {
            arr[colStart][j] = arr[colStart][j + 1];
        }
        for (int i = rowStart; i < rowEnd; i++)
        {
            arr[i][colEnd] = arr[i + 1][colEnd];
        }
        for (int i = colEnd; i > colStart; i--)
        {
            arr[rowEnd][i] = arr[rowEnd][i - 1];
        }
        for (int i = rowEnd; i > rowStart; i--)
        {
            arr[i][colStart] = arr[i - 1][colStart];
        }

        if (rows == 1)
        {
            arr[colEnd][rowStart] = temp;
        }
        else
            arr[rowStart + 1][colStart] = temp;

        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------\n");
        rotate(arr, rowStart + 1, rowEnd - 1, colStart + 1, colEnd - 1);
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clockwise rotation by 90 degrees. O(n^2) time and O(1) memory in Python3:

```
# @param A : list of list of integers
# @return the same list modified
def rotate(A):
    for row in range(len(A) // 2):
        for col in range(row, len(A)-1 - row): # First col already takes care of last.
            r = row
            c = col
            tmp1 = A[r][c]
            while True:
                next_r = c
                next_c = len(A) - 1 - r
                tmp2 = A[next_r][next_c]
                A[next_r][next_c] = tmp1
                if next_r == row and next_c == col:
                    break
                tmp1 = tmp2
                r = next_r
                c = next_c
    return A
```

Comment: Consider adding some comments. Code only answers are not adviced.